# creating a new development profile, unknown team

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, ios-provisioning

I have a new iPhone 5 and I would like to add to the development list.

So, I add this as "development" from Xcode, and I create a new development profile from IOS Provisioning Portal.

The certificate is created and asociated to the device:

[image]

This development profile is valid for all the ios devices in my company.

I download the profile as usual, and install in XCode, but the team is unknown:

How can I solve this?
[image]

Comment: Try to use organizer (xcode -> top right button) -> provision profiles -> refresh

Comment: it worked!! I tried a lot of thinks except refresh.

Comment: I added it as answer. (mark it as the solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use refresh your `provision profiles`:

Open `XCode` and navigate to `organizer` (top right button). 
Then go to `provision profiles` and click on `refresh`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be correct anymore. Does anyone have an update on this answer?